# check engine light 2006 kia sedona

Tags: cel, kia, sedona

I had the oil changed on my Kia Sedona 2006 about 8 weeks ago . After I left the repair shop the check engine light came on. They rest it but it came back on. I tried to DEQ my Sedona and it would not pass. I am told it is due to a vacuum leak! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Take it to a workshop and have it fixed. One of your induction pipes either cracked or came undone while they were busy. Although it's weird how an oil change can cause this. I wouldn't take my car back to the same place.